# How to transfer all folders in user profile using USMT tool?

Tags: xml, batch-file, cmd, migration

I have been working on a tool to automate USMT migrations to be working in enterprise level.

The USMT tool is working perfectly fine and migrating the system_folders inside the user profile, i.e:

```
C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop
C:\Users\%Username%\Documents
C:\Users\%Username%\Pictures
etc.
```

However if I have a non system_folder inside the user profile such as `C:\Users\%Username%\MyData` it does not get transferred.

How do I include all the folders inside the user profile to be transferred?

I tried fiddling around in the default `MigUser.xml/custom.xml` files created but no luck.

**Edit:** Below is the tool code used to run the scan state:

```
scanstate C:\ /i:migapp.xml /i:miguser.xml /ue:*\* /ui:DOMAIN\* /o /c /v:13 /localonly
```

Comment: How can we help you to identify the issue if you haven't provided the code you are having the issue with or any information about the folder which isn't being transferred?

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question with the USMT code used to deploy and capture the .MIG file

Comment: You haven't explained what exactly isn't being transferred or what you've edited or added to the XML file(s).

Comment: I just did, again in a basic user profile you have these folder: Contact/Desktop/Documents/Downloads/Music/Videos.
These folder gets transferred fine, however if I create a new folder that is called "My NewFolder" under the user profile, it does not get transferred using the tool

Comment: As of now, no editing is done in the XML, I am using the default Migapp and Miguser XML's